# How to get corresponding one hot labels from weight matrix?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix

I run training loop for a set of data points say 1,2,3 and 4. At every point I run training loop for 20000 training steps. For every data point I get a different W matrix (Fully connected).

```
`W_fc = weight_variable([input_dim, 2])
logits = tf.matmul(pool_2D, W_fc)`
```

My goal is to plot a graph between set of data points on x-axis and W-matrix on y-axis but it need some kind of transformation. Considering a single data point 
 and its corresponding W-matrix I have to multiply weight matrix with one hot vector that was assigned at data point 1. At each single data point each W-matrix has dimension of (40,2) and one hot vector should have dimension (2,1) for matrix multiplication. So how can I get one hot vector corresponding to particular data point?

```
    `for hc in h_array:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        data_sets = input_rfhm.read_data_sets("Input", str(hc), one_hot=True)

        for i in range(FLAGS.training_step):
            batch = data_sets.train.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
            optimizer.run(feed_dict = {x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})

            if(i%100 ==0):
                train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict= {x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
                test_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict= {x: data_sets.test.MC_Samples, y_: data_sets.test.labels})
            loss_value = loss.eval(feed_dict= {x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})`
```